# Is there a subsequence of $a_n = n \sin(n)$ which tends to $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know there is such a subsequence for $b_n = \sin(n)$. What about $a_n = n\sin(n)$?

Comment: can you please clarify on what it is you are trying to ask?

Comment: @Abel, $n$ has to be a natural number.

Comment: This was asked recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390452/is-zero-a-cluster-point-of-n-sin-n?lq=1 See also the last comment in the following answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/221168/405

Comment: The basic question is whether $\sin i$ is close enough to zero often enough.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this is an open problem?

Comment: At its core, the fundamental question is the following: given $\epsilon > 0$ small, what is the expected growth rate of $n_{\epsilon}$, where $n_{\epsilon}$ is the first integer such that $n_{\epsilon} \equiv \pm \epsilon$ mod $\pi$.

Comment: Christopher A. Wong, there won't usually be any $n_\epsilon$ like that. What do you actually mean?

Comment: Computing with $n$ from 1 to 2 million there exists only $15$ values of $n$ such that $-1<n\cdot \sin(n)<1$. Of course this is not a proof, but sugests that maybe this subsequence does not exists.

Comment: Going up to $5$ million and we still have only $15$ values.

Comment: @dfeuer, Sorry, I meant that $n_{\epsilon} \le \epsilon$ mod $\pi$; you can show using the pigeonhole principle that for $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n$ is at most $\epsilon$ away from some multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @Integral, how are you doing these computations? They need to be rather absurdly precise to give the right results.

Comment: why rather absurdly? It's necessary to be only 1 digit precise.

Comment: The computation of $sin(n)$ will need to be precise since $n$ is so large and will "move" many decimals to the left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does $a_n = n\sin n$ have a convergent subsequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665644/does-a-n-n-sin-n-have-a-convergent-subsequence)