# Limit points of the set $\{n\sin(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to find limit points of the set $\{ n\sin(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N \}$. According to me set is dense in $\mathbb R$ as $\sin(n)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.  Any suggestions please. Solution of same problem is given in [Is $n \sin n$ dense on the real line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221018/is-n-sin-n-dense-on-the-real-line) but unable to understand. Can I got short way to thinking it’s limit points ?

Comment: Seems difficult. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221018/is-n-sin-n-dense-on-the-real-line).

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309306/accumulation-points-of-x-n-in-mathbbr-n-in-mathbbn-x-n-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).