# limit inferior of sequence $a_n = n^2 \sin^2(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I see the problem $\limsup_{n\to\infty}({sin(n)}), \liminf_{n\to\infty}({sin(n)})$. And i prove it with dirichlet approximation. Also Through this, i prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty}({n\
sin^2(n)})=0$. so i think what is $\limsup_{n\to\infty}({n^2 \sin^2(n)})$. but i cannnot do it. How can i know $\limsup_{n\to\infty}({n^2 \sin^2(n)})$. is there other theorems like dirichlet approximation theorem?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83550/has-n2sinn-limit Related.  Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown/20609#20609.

Comment: It's [probably $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725321/how-would-you-evaluate-liminf-limits-n-to-infty-n-mathopen-sin-n), but if the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is exactly $2$ it might be positive.